# Cloning Table tr into backbone template

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am pretty new to backbone.js. I have the following setup

```
Scripts
|--App
|   |--collecions
|   |    |----students.js
|   |--model
|   |    |---student.js
|   |--views
|   |    |---Header-View.js
|   |    |---Stud-List-View.js
|   |    |---Stud-Item-List-View.js
|   |    |---StudView.js
|   |--app.js
|--Templates
|   |-----Header.htm
|   |-----StudTable.htm
|   |-----student.htm
|--main.js
```

The StudTable.html is like this -----

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
<caption>Student Details </caption>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Age
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{firstname}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{lastname}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{age}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I render the collection send from here

```
function ($, _, Backbone, Student, StudList, HeaderView, StudView, ListView, CloneView) {
 var AppView = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         "": "list",
         "students/clone": "clone",            
     },

     initialize: function () {
         var view = new HeaderView();
         return this;
     },
     clone: function () {
         var studs = new StudList();
         studs.fetch({
             success: function () {
                 $("#content").html(new CloneView({ collection: studs }).el);
             }
         });
     },

 });    

 return AppView;
});
```

How can I show the collection there in table with help of jQuery cloning without touching the format of html template? Is there any way we can clone into the table for each element in the collection?

I don't want to use something like two views like this question

[Render Html Table with underscore template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257401/render-html-table-with-underscore-template-engine-using-a-backbone-complex-model)

They have used two views: one for tbody and another for appending tr to tbody. I want to do it in a single view, with the help of the template mentioned above. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Honestly 2 views is the way to go. 1 main view for the entire page (or the entire `<table>` or `<tbody>`, and then another view for each `<tr>`. Why do you want to accomplish everything with one view? If you do choose to try that, then it will likely be a pure JS or jQuery solution that has very little to do with Backbone.js.

Comment: @BenjaminSmith Well actually I thought I would Clone the tr within that view only . And render into Tbody. Well As I guess already the Template contains the firstname , lastname and age . So I was wondering if there was any way to render it within tbody via cloning the Tr

Comment: You could extract the `<tr>`, let your template engine compile it, build the HTML, and then do a `$('tbody').html(html)` to finish it off. Sounds like a lot of extra work though.

Comment: @muistooshort So which one should be better ? Having a single View two different templates ? or Having single Template and two different views ? I am very new to backbone so pardon for my noobness

Comment: @BenjaminSmith is right, two templates or one template with a loop wrapped around the `<tr>` is the way to go.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes I understood that . But which one would be better ? with two views or Two templates ? I mean which has less work to be done ?

Comment: One view with one template and a loop inside the template would probably be the easiest, then split it into two views (with one template each) when things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments, you should use 2 views and 2 templates. I don't see any advantage at all to the "cloning" mechanism in the original post - that's not the Backbone way!

The main App view will render the main page HTML, and each individual `<tr>` view will represent a record in the database/datamodel. So render the main App view, and then loop through your JSON response to render each `<tr>` view individually.

From there, you can add, delete, and sort rows with ease. Because each view will be tied directly to a model instance, the two can "talk" to one another very easily (yay Backone!).

This site helped me learn the best way to organize my Backbone applications when i first started:
http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#sub_views

Comment: As an afterthought, the [To-do MVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/) project has an excellent example of rendering list items within a list. They use `<ul>` and `<li>`s in the example, but the same idea applies. See lines 74-83 of the [main app view](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app.js) of the example.